# Undertow servlet handler looses already authenticated and valid SecurityContext managed by keycloak

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, keycloak, undertow

I'm trying to enable role based access control on a rest end point that I've setup using undertow, jersey and CDI. I initialize the servlet deployment as follows:

```
DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = Servlets.deployment()
    .setClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader())
    .setContextPath("/rest")
    .setDeploymentName("sv.war")
    .addListeners(listener(Listener.class))
    .setLoginConfig(new LoginConfig("KEYCLOAK", "some-realm"))
    .setAuthorizationManager(auth) // my dummy for testing
    .addServlets(servlet("jerseyServlet", ServletContainer.class)
        .setLoadOnStartup(1)
        .addInitParam("javax.ws.rs.Application", SystemViewApplication.class.getName())
        .addMapping("/api/*"));
```

I enabled kecloak authentication based on [this example code](https://github.com/iperdomo/undertow-keycloak/blob/master/src/main/java/SecuredServer.java).

So, my server is started as:

```
DeploymentManager manager = Servlets.defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
manager.deploy();

PathHandler path = Handlers.path(Handlers.resource(staticResources).setDirectoryListingEnabled(false).setWelcomeFiles("index.html"))
    .addPrefixPath("/rest", manager.start());
Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
    .addHttpListener(8087, "localhost")
    .setHandler(sessionHandling(addSecurity(exchange -> {
      final SecurityContext context = exchange.getSecurityContext();
      if (!context.isAuthenticated()) {
        exchange.endExchange();
        return;
      }
      log.info("Authenticated: {} {} {}", context.getMechanismName(), context.getAuthenticatedAccount().getPrincipal().getName(), context.getAuthenticatedAccount().getRoles());
      // propagate the request
      path.handleRequest(exchange);
    })))
    .build();
server.start();
```

Where the two methods `sessionHandling()` and `addSecurity()` are lifted from the example I've linked above.

The authentication works, I am forced to log in, and the `Authenticated: ..` logging line is printed out with the correct details. But, once it hits the servlet handling, the security context (and account) is lost. I've traced this call and I can see that at some point along the path, it's replaced by brand new `SecurityContext` which has a null account.

Now my question - is there some authentication mechanism that I am missing that would propagate the state after the keycloak authentication or can I just fix the undertow code and in the `SecurityContext`, if the passed in context is already correctly authenticated, accept that state and move on? (the latter doesn't seem right, I'm guessing it's because the could be different authentication for the servlet deployment?) If so, is there any way to connect the servlet deployment to see the keycloak authentication has already happened?

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone comes looking here on how to authenticate servlets properly with keycloak and use role based authentication, this worked for me (note, this worked for me without the requirement of any xml files, purely with annotations.

First in the servlet application (wherever you extended `ResourceConfig`) `register()` the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class`.

Also enable `"use-resource-role-mappings": true` in `keycloak.json`.

Next, instantiate the servlet deployment with an initial security wrapper:

```
DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = Servlets.deployment()
    .setClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader())
    .setContextPath("/")
    .setDeploymentName("sv.war")
    .addListeners(listener(Listener.class))
    .setIdentityManager(idm)
    .setSessionManagerFactory(new InMemorySessionManagerFactory())
    .setInitialSecurityWrapper(handler -> sessionHandling(addSecurity(handler)))
    .setResourceManager(staticResources)
    .addWelcomePage("index.html")
    .addServlets(servlet("jerseyServlet", ServletContainer.class)
        .setLoadOnStartup(1)
        .addInitParam("javax.ws.rs.Application", SystemViewApplication.class.getName())
        .addMapping("/api/*"));


DeploymentManager manager = Servlets.defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
manager.deploy();

Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
    .addHttpListener(8087, "localhost")
    .setHandler(Handlers.path(manager.start()))
    .build();
server.start();
```

Where `sessionHandling(addSecurity(handler))` is basically the code from the linked github repo.

Now authentication via keycloak will work, and also role based authentication will work, so for example, if you have a CDI injected rest end point, such as:

```
@RolesAllowed({"admin", "guest"})
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public Response findById(@PathParam("id") @NotNull Integer id){
  // some method
}
```

As long as the roles are configured in keycloak, it should work.